# Kaggle API on Windows 7

Tags: python, kaggle

I am new to Kaggle and was hoping to use the API to download and submit my work. I followed the instructions in the Read the Docs section which suggested

```
pip install kaggle
```

When creating a new API token it tells you to put the json file in the folder called ".kaggle". That folder doesn't exist.

I'm using Anacondas, and get the message "Requirement already satisfied". I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling it, but have not gotten that folder to appear anywhere in C. I've scoured stack overflow (and other Google results) but haven't seen this issue resolved anywhere. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, you need to create the `.kaggle` folder here first: `C:\Users\<Windows-username>\`, e.g. with `mkdir`. Then you can place the `kaggle.json` file there.

In case it helps, there's more related discussion on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api/issues/15.